SSR/Structural search in JavaScript object literal
I want to be able to find a property (myProp) in a JS object literal using SSR.
{
    myProp: 1,
    otherProp: 2,
}

With {myProp: $expr$} I receive no results.
How can I represent the remaining properties?
